# Using SCSS with Flask

Tags: python, flask, sass

I'm trying to use scss with Flask and get it to auto-compile.

I've tried using [Flask-Scss](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Scss/) — unfortunately, when I set it up, I get `Scanning acceleration disabled (_speedups not found)!` errors, and no CSS file. Anyone know how to fix this, or get it to generate CSS files?

Comment: What is your platform? You'll need a C compiler available to compile the `_speedups` module, although the pure Python version should also work, albeit slower.

Comment: I'm on OS X, & my server is running Debian. Where do I find the `_speedups` module?

Comment: The `_speedups` module is part of the _Flask-Scss_ sources. It is compile from _C_ sources when you install _Flask-Scss_. Do you have _Xcode_ installed?

Comment: I do have XCode installed. When I installed Flask-Scss, it didn't compile anything. I have everything installed into a virtualenv, would that prevent it compiling?

Comment: I've installed it in a virtualenv in Ubuntu Linux and everything, including dependencies, installed flawlessly. Unfortunately I don't have Mac OS X to test it there. Have a look at the console output during installation to see if you spot any error or warning messages that may help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The error results from an error in the installation process. If you install through `pip` on an Ubuntu system and you get this warning:

```
==========================================================================
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python installation succeeded.
==========================================================================
```

Then you should make sure you have the `libpcre3-dev` library pre-installed (this is the module that contains `pcre.h`, the module that the C-installation fails on):

```
 apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

After doing this, re-install Flask-Scss:

```
pip install Flask-scss --force-reinstall -I
```

After restarting the Flask server, the error should now be a thing of the past.

### But, please note

Even though the above will solve the problem of the `_speedups not found` error showing up,  there is another likely reason for your files not getting compiled. If you have code like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

from flask.ext.scss import Scss
Scss(app, static_dir='static', asset_dir='assets')

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

, and you are not setting `debug` anywhere else, then you should make sure to put

```
app.debug = True
```

**before** the invocation of the Scss object:

```
app.debug = True
Scss(app, static_dir='static', asset_dir='assets')
```

Happiness! That should do the trick for getting your .scss files to compile every time you load a page in debug mode.